# Overriding Bootstrap CSS for 'btn-xs' With New Class

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, odoo-8

Hi I am new to Bootstrap and would like to override 'btn-xs' with new height width and padding. Essentially making th button smaller than it is and also the text will be reduced too.

I have tried adding a new class 'custom' on the following line of code but it does not take affect.

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-xs custom" style=""> Filter</button>
```

Bellow is my custom css:

```
custom {
font-size: 10px;
padding: 1px 10px}
```

I'm probably doing something extremely stupid. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid using !important you can try to be more spesific.

The button is probably affected by this rule set in the bootstrap CSS:

```
.btn-group-xs>.btn, .btn-xs { ... }
```

Try:

```
.btn-group-xs>.btn.custom, .btn-xs.custom {
font-size: 10px;
padding: 1px 10px}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this but seems like btn-xs still overrides the custom css. My button has the following classes:
'<button class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-filter custom"> Filter</button>'

Comment: If you look at this element with eg. Firebug, you will see what rule is overriding your rule. Also make sure the link to your custom CSS-file is placed after the default bootstrap.css

Answer (score 0):

Try with !important, for example font-size: 10px !important